# Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision

Tags: batch-file, cmd, numbers, integer, numeric

Found this script on the net. It works for the basic reason I downloaded it. But I would like to know a couple things:

1. When the script attempt to divide the bytes to KB, MG and GB it errors with 
   Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
2. Total Number for Files & Directories are missing the close parenthesis.

**CODE:**

```
c:
cd\
@Echo ------------------------------------------------------
@Echo ------------------------------------------------------
@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"hostname"') do @Set summaryouthost=%%a
@Echo Integrity Check on: %summaryouthost%

@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"chdir"') do @Set summaryoutchdir=%%a
@Echo Integrity Check For the path: %summaryoutchdir%
@Echo ------------------------------------------------------

@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"date /T"') do @Set summaryoutsdate=%%a
@Echo Start Date: %summaryoutsdate%

@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"time /T"') do @Set summaryoutstime=%%a
@Echo Start time: %summaryoutstime%

@Echo ------------------------------------------------------
@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"dir /s /-c | find "bytes" | find /v "free""')  do @Set summaryout=%%a
::@Echo %summaryout%
@For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("%summaryout%") do @set filesout=%%a&set sizeout=%%b
@For /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"dir /s /-c | find "bytes free""') do @Set summaryoutdir=%%a
::@Echo %summaryoutdir%
@For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("%summaryoutdir%") do @set filesoutdir=%%a&set sizeoutdir=%%b
@Set sizeout=%sizeout:bytes=%
::@Echo %sizeout%

@Set sizeout=%sizeout: =%
@set /A inbytes=%sizeout%
@set /A inkb=(%sizeout%) / 1024
@set /A inmb=(%sizeout%) / (1024*1024)
@set /A ingb=(%sizeout%) / (1024*1024*1024)

@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"date /T"') do @Set summaryoutedate=%%a
@Echo End Date: %summaryoutedate%

@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"time /T"') do @Set summaryoutetime=%%a
@Echo End time: %summaryoutetime%

@Echo ------------------------------------------------------
@Echo Total Number of Files is:%filesout%
@Echo Total Number of Directory is: %filesoutdir%
@Set sizeoutdir=%sizeoutdir:bytes=%
::@Echo %sizeoutdir%
@Set sizeoutdir=%sizeoutdir: =%
@Echo ------------------------------------------------------
@Echo Total Size is (BY) :%sizeout%
@Echo Total Size is (KB) :%inkb%
@Echo Total Size is (MB) :%inmb%
@Echo Total Size is (GB) :%ingb%
@Echo ------------------------------------------------------
@Echo Free Space is :%sizeoutdir%
@Echo ------------------------------------------------------
@Echo ------------------------------------------------------
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
------------------------------------------------------ 
------------------------------------------------------ 
Integrity Check on: Laptop01 
Integrity Check For the path: C:\ 
------------------------------------------------------ 
Start Date: Sun 10/04/2015  
Start time: 12:34 AM
------------------------------------------------------
Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of presision.
Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of presision.
Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of presision.
Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of presision.
End Date: Sun 10/04/2015   
End time: 12:36 AM  
------------------------------------------------------ 
Total Number of Files is:333914 File(s 
Total Number of Directory is: 185869 Dir(s 
------------------------------------------------------ 
Total Size is (BY) :248159912076  
Total Size is (KB) : 
Total Size is (MB) : 
Total Size is (GB) : 
------------------------------------------------------ 
Free Space is :625324642304free  
------------------------------------------------------ 
------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Any file sizes over roughly 3Gb will exceed the 32bit integer size.

Comment: @Granity - Actually the limit is 2Gb.

Comment: The closing perentheses at the total number of files and folders are missing because the code is simply removing them; So you nee to append them manually...

Answer (score 5):

#### Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.

This is a limitation of `set /a`.

For workarounds see "Workarounds: 32-bit" below.

> Arithmetic expressions (SET /a)
>
> ...
>
> The numbers must all be within the range of 32 bit signed integer
>   numbers (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647) to handle larger
>   numbers use PowerShell or VBScript.

Source [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

---

#### Workarounds: 32-bit

> Workarounds for the 32-bit limitation include:
>
> 1. dividing by 1000 (or any power of 10) by chopping off the last (3) digits
> 2. splitting up the numbers into separate decimal digits and perform all the math and carry logic "manually"
> 3. other scripting languages
>
> Workaround #1 can be used to add up disk space:
>
> - ["Chop" code example](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/add_nt.txt)
>
> The trick is that each (big) number is treated as strings, then the
>   rightmost 6 characters (digits) are chopped off, and only then the
>   result is treated as a number.
>
> This is a rather crude workaround, as it "rounds" all numbers before
>   doing the math.
>
> Adding half a MegaByte for each subdirectory (%Count% / 2) to %Total%
>   does compensate for the truncations, though, so the grand total is
>   more accurate than the individual numbers.
>
> Note that the numbers don't represent "real" MegaBytes (1024 x 1024)
>   buth rather Million Bytes (1000 x 1000).
>
> Workaround #2 is perfectly demonstrated by Brian Williams' batch
>   files:
>
> - [Add.bat](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/add_nt.txt)
> - [IsLarger.cmd](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/islarger_3rdparty_bat.txt)
> - [Multiply.cmd](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/multiply_3rdparty_bat.txt)
>
> Workaround #3, other scripting languages, is self-explanatory.

Source [Math in NT batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an easy cheat for diskspace, you can do a cruder calculation by subsetting the string and dividing by an approximation. Like so:

```
@set /A ingb=%sizeout:~0,-7% / (1074)
```

Where %sizeout:~0,-7% substrings sizeout, which is a crude way of dividing by 1.000.000 without handling any issues of rounding,
and where 1074 is calculated 1024*1024*1024 / 1.000.000

The same would be done for all the size you need (KB and MB).

MB: `%sizeout:~0,-4% / 1049`

KB: `%sizeout:~0,-4%`

Of course the numbers would be increasingly inaccurate the lower the measurement-units, but for GB it was plenty accurate for me to use it to monitor disk space on machines.

I realise that all of this can also be deducted from DavidPostill's answer, but I just wanted to bring a copy paste example that applies to this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

And even better solution.

Accurate to mb precision for sizes up to few GB.

Read the remarks in the code for better understanding.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Asign filesize to a string variable
set FileSizeString=%~z1

:: Get the lenght of the string
for /L %%x in (1,1,25) do ( if "!FileSizeString:~%%x!"=="" set /a "Lenght=%%x" & goto LenghtResult )

:LenghtResult 
rem If lenght of the filesize string is below or equal 9. Numbers: 0 - 999,999,999
if !Lenght! leq 9 (set /a SizeMb=!FileSizeString!/1024/1024
    rem If lenght of the filesize string is not below or equal 9 then remove its last 3 characters
    ) else (set FileSizeString=!FileSizeString:~0,-3!)

rem If lenght of the filesize string is equal 10. Numbers: 1,000,000,000 - 9,999,999,999
if !Lenght! equ 10 (
    rem If first character of the filesize string is equal 1. Numbers: 1,000,000,000 - 1,999,999,999
    if "!FileSizeString:~0,1!" equ "1" (set /a SizeMb=!FileSizeString!/1049
        rem If first character of the filesize string is not equal 1. Numbers: 2,000,000,000 - 9,999,999,999
        ) else (set /a SizeMb=!FileSizeString!/1074) )

rem If lenght of the filesize string is above or equal 11. Numbers: 10,000,000,000 - 999,999,999,999,999...
if !Lenght! geq 11 (set /a SizeMb=!FileSizeString!/1074)    

:: Displays file name and it's size in mb
echo.
echo File: %~nx1
echo Size: !SizeMb!mb
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will get the total physical memory in gig.

```
@echo off
Rem This will produce a file for total ram
    Wmic Computersystem get totalphysicalmemory > c:\temp\trash\allram1.txt
Rem This will produce a clean text file with true value
     type c:\temp\trash\allram1.txt > c:\temp\trash\allram3.txt
REm  The following will skip a line (header)
    (    for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("c:\temp\trash\allram3.txt") do echo(%%L) > "c:\temp\trash\allram4.txt"

Rem following will produce a clean file with actual number
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
    set /p val=<c:\temp\trash\allram4.txt
    set newval=!val:~10,1!

rem it will find the new value wheter it is more than 10 gig
    echo !newval!   > c:\temp\trash\allram2.txt
rem This will determine if more than 10 gig is found (less than 10 gig) (more than 10 gig)
 findstr "off" c:\temp\trash\allram2.txt && (set  newval2=!val:~0,1!.!val:~1,1!) || (set newval2= !val:~0,2!)

rem if it is less than 10 gig it will have decimal for example 8.2gig or 17gig (if it is more 10 gig) 
echo !newval2!gig
```